# Finding root path of image via chrome inspector css

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am editing a wordpress template and i need to find the html class/id ".navbar-header" so i can see in the html what image it links to. So i can change the image too double size.

How to i find the root path of this image? So i can change the image. I was finding this current css part with chrome inspector tool.

```css
/* MADS EDIT sticy nav from 100% to 215%

orignal code here:
.sticky-nav .navbar-header img {
    max-height: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

*/

.sticky-nav .navbar-header img {
    max-height: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to network panel of chrome dev tools
Go to images panel inside it
reload the page and find your image in it
check the image url :)

Answer (score 0):

That is quite simple:

1. Move your mouse over the image.
2. Right-click and choose inspect.
3. Now in the elements tab you can see the inspected image with it's src.

<sub>*I tested on the pic of your SO signature.*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

> How to i find the root path of this image? So i can change the image.

Finding the "`root path`(directory path)" of a file on a server, is not possible on *frontend* unless the the website uses the apache(server) root as its own root.

Why I say so,

The server could be using a folder placed deep inside the server root folder to serve the website but still the image link will appear just relative to the domain.

eg.

```
The url of the website is say 
http://example.com

Web root folder on server:
/var/www/html/websites/myprojects/2016/example/

The Path to the image would be
/var/www/html/websites/myprojects/2016/example/images/myimg.jpeg`

The location of the image shown on frontend would be.
http://example.com/images/myimg.jpeg
```